# Hololens Emulator: Unreal Engine app completely black, though Win64 works

Tags: unreal-engine4, hololens, hololens-emulator

I have taken the "default game" (tables and chairs) of Unreal Engine 4.26, and packaged it for the Hololens emulator using [these instructions](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/XRDevelopment/AR/HoloLens/HowTo/PackageApp/index.html).

I can launch the latest Hololens emulator (10.0.19041.1136) and install the Unreal application, and an icon shows up for it in the apps panel. But when I launch the app, the entire screen is black. When packaging the application for Windows (64 bit), the application works just fine.

What could be the issue? Older versions of Unreal Engine work fine, in particular I have verified that Unreal Engine version 4.25 works with the emulator.

Other perhaps relevant info: Intel Core i7-5960X, Windows 10 version 1909 build 18363.1440, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, Version 456.71.

I have also used the Unreal 4.26-chaos engine, completely fresh. I choose a blank project from the Games category, C++, Scalable 2D or 3D, raytracing disabled, mobile/tablet with starter content. Then add the Microsoft Windows Mixed reality plugin and the Hololens plugin.  In settings I get a signing certificate and define a project name, using Windows SDK version 10.0.18362. Again, no joy. The same thing, just as a Blueprint, not a C++ project, also does not work.

Also checked Hololens emulator version 10.0.19041.1117. No joy.

Comment: We tested the "tables and chairs" scene but cannot reproduce this issue, and it works on the HoloLens2 emulator(Unreal 4.26.1; HoloLens 2 Emulator (10.0.19041.1131)). By the way, HoloLens 2 Emulator only supports x86 or x64 App, so that you should select the x64 *.appx dependency package file for the emulator in your outputted project directory instead of arm64. Could you double-check this point when you are deploying?  For more information please see: https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/XRDevelopment/AR/HoloLens/QuickStartEmulator/index.html

Comment: I have double checked this point, and still have the same problem. Moreover, the app does not work on ARM64 on the Hololens either.

Comment: Please make sure that all your shaders have 0 transparency in display output.

Comment: @AndreyChistyakov: Just searched for the in the Unreal Engine Project settings; didn't find an option to set transparency in display output. Where is this setting?

Answer (score 1):

We followed all the steps exactly per docs including the “run in VR mode setting” in packaging and reproduced this issue today.

So, we are going to recommend to you to file a defect over with UE 4.26 via [Unreal Engine Support | Get Help and Customer Service for UE - Unreal Engine](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-us/support). Besides, you can also open a support case via http://aka.ms/hololenssupport for free to discuss further too on anything we can offer for HoloLens 2 emulator/device:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue in the Epic's article. You should enable the "start in VR" option in Project > Description > Settings as from

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unreal/tutorials/unreal-uxt-ch6

It was added in 4.26.

And we don't support Unreal 4.26-**chaos** yet. Please take simple 4.26.

Comment: I just tried this. No joy. The project does have three balls that circle each other before crashing though, which is more than what I had previously.

Comment: I repeated all your steps with two exceptions - "start in VR" enabled and chaos disabled, and all was working. Please provide more details